# Why does this WPF multibinding return null?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got this confusing situation in XAML:

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ExcludeMemberCountCommand}">
    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OrderExclusionConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
            <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}"/>
            <Binding Path="." />
        </MultiBinding>
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
    <CheckBox.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OrderExclusionParamConverter}">
            <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}"/>
            <Binding Path="." />
        </MultiBinding>
    </CheckBox.CommandParameter>
</CheckBox>
```

The idea is that two parameters are needed to determine whether the box starts out as "checked" or not, and that if the user checks the box (firing the command), those same two parameters will be needed to save the data into the database.

This is inside a collection-bound ListView control, in a column that contains a grid databound to another collection. So it's not straightforward to save this state with ViewModel properties. I did try to use SelectedItem on the ListView, but ran into all sorts of problems, so fell back on a Multibinding.

The `IsChecked` binding and converter works fine, and correctly preselects checkboxes to check. However, I noticed that at binding time, the `OrderExclusionConverter` also binds. It contains the expected values when it does. Here's the converter.

```
public class OrderExclusionParameterConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So far, so good. However, when I check an empty checkbox, fire the command and hit a breakpoint in the command code, the object that's passed down has two null values in place of the bound values. Why?

Also - is there a better way of doing this? I hate that what I'm doing here is effectively duplicating code in the XAML and Converters.

Comment: Can you see in debugger that `Convert` of `OrderExclusionParameterConverter` is triggered and has some `values`? Also just to confirm that it's not a typo and you're using correct resource resource name is `OrderExclusionParamConverter` and class name is `OrderExclusionParameterConverter`

Comment: @dkozl Yes, and yes. The debugger hits the param converter when the page loads and has the correct values. It does *not* hit the converter a second time when the box is clicked.

Comment: @CédricBignon Good question. It stops the converter trying to work the opposite way (i.e the "ConvertBack" portion) when it's not necessary and saves a lot of headache when you only want to convert values going in.

Comment: You are binding the result of OrderExclusionParameterConverter to a IsChecked property. IsChecked is boolean, unfortunately you return array of objects from your converter.

It's not about nullness, just be careful

Comment: @norekhov I don't think so. I'm binding the ParamConverter to a CommandParameter property. IsChecked is bound to a very similar converter, but it's not actually the same one - it parses the values and returns a Boolean.

Comment: @matt yes, my mistake, sorry.